# pipe % and predict()

Tags: r, predict

I am using `predict()` in a logistic model and piping the data. Below is the code:

```
library (dplyr)
data %>%
 mutate(
    y = predict(model, data, type = "response"),
    odds_ratio = y / (1 - y),
    log_odds_ratio = log(odds_ratio),
    log_odds_ratio2 = predict(model, data)
  )
```

data: a tibble of x (one column only),
model: `glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial, data = data)`

I have 2 questions about the last column log_odds_ratio2:

1. How `predict()` knows that it should take log_odds_ratio and original x to calculate the new prediction (since there are 3 new columns created before)?
2. Why `type = "response"` is not needed in `predict()`?

Comment: See argument `type` in `?predict.glm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in following page, [description about predict function in case of glm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/predict.glm), default argument for `terms` is `link`, which means log odds ratio. and I think this can be also explain about question 2.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I realized that I have mistaken the function. I thought it is taking new data created by mutate, but it is not. It is still taking the original x and just use prediction() with its default type (as shown in the page you provided: ...for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds...). Now it is clear. Thank you!